# OH-TFS-Connecto​​r-0051 error

Tags: opshub

I was able to migrate most of the projects to VSO except for two. I'm getting this error:

com.opshub.eai.​​tfs.exception.​O​IMTFSApiExcep​ti​on:
OH-TFS-Connecto​​r-0051: Operation failed getUserList. Server Error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Key note: I'm using the OpsHub migration tool for migrating Team Foundation Server on-premise to Visual Studion Online. I don't have the code running behind the scene.

Please help

Comment: Add more detail. Show us the code that is causing that problem. No one can help you with such little detail.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in version OVSMU-V1.0.1.006.exe.

You can downlod it from visualstudiogallery

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2/file/132237/5/OVSMU-V1.0.1.006.exe